# from Eclipse to Android phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have made a program on eclipse. But how can I get the program from eclipse to my phone? I have a cable because it probably wont make a QR code like appinventor does huh. How do i install my app on there?

Comment: it depends. what type of program did you made? java c++ etc but you will be able to reuse some code if it is in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows you will need drivers to install for the particular device that you have. And if you are on Linux, there is a rules.txt file in which you have to make entries with the device UID. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up your machine and phone for running and debugging from eclipse.  It involves getting the phone's usb driver on your machine, and setting up the phone for usb debugging.

Read this [Using Hardware Devices | Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply export the apk file and copy it to your phone. Email it to yourself, bluetooth transfer, upload to a server then download on your phone.... come on.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to allow the device to accept nonsigned apps and USB debugging (change this in your device's app configuration). Then, if you have the drivers (you can install them within your AVD), you can just run the app from Eclipse in your phone.

Comment: Android does not accept nonsigned apps (and there are no settings to allow this, unless you modify Android OS). But when you run applications from eclipe you use "debug" certificate which is generated by Android SDK.

Comment: @inazuruk Yes you can... http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/installing-non-market-apps-on-android.html